# React Native FlatList consuming all touches (ToucableWithoutFeedback onPress not called)

Tags: ios, react-native, touch, react-native-flatlist

I have a `FlatList` in my React Native app and I'm rendering regular cells. I've added `Touchable`s and `onPress` events as usual inside the cells but my cells aren't receiving touch events. I'm currently on iOS and I've tried to intercept touch events (by overriding `UIApplication`s `touchesBegan:withEvent:` method in Xcide) but for some reason the application isn't receiving touch events when tapped inside the `FlatList` (the method isn't called). Flat list scrolls fine (gesture recognizer works), but somehow the app (and none of the views) isn't receiving touch events. If I tap anywhere outside the bounds of the `FlatList`, touches are received and processed correctly.

How can I make touch events work normally? I'm on React Native 0.59.8.

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: @Tim it's too long and under NDA, otherwise I'd add. I'm looking for any common pitfalls that might be causing the issue

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. In general onPress works perfectly in FlatLists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug with React Native (even though the bug is closed due to inactivity, this is exactly what is happening with me too) at https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23740. I've switched to `TouchableOpacity` with opacity set to 1 (to mimic the same visual behavior) and the problem went away. Even though this is not a real solution rather a workaround, the bug originates from React Native itself so I think going with the workaround is the best *solution* for now.